# Problens printing Logs in a pipeline step on Azure AI - Machine Learning Studio

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-ai

I am ussing the azure AI - Machine Learning Studio to adapt and run a pipeline. I am executing the code in the jupyter notebook at my workspace but when I run the STEP 1 I can't see the print or logging in the output cell of jupyter notebook. The step run fine, and return the values expected but the prints are not showed.

The STEP 1 code in jupyter notebook is:

```
##############
### STEP 1 ###
##############

# Create Output object for step1
output_step1 = OutputFileDatasetConfig('files_to_process').read_delimited_files().register_on_complete('files_to_process')

# Create Python Script Step for define files to be processed
data_prep_step = PythonScriptStep(name="Check for Non-processed Files",
                        script_name="dataprep.py", 
                        arguments = ["--output-dir", output_step1, "--node-count", GB_NODE_COUNT, "--process-count", GB_PROCESS_COUNT_PER_NODE, "--batch-size", GB_BATCH_SIZE],
                        runconfig = data_steps_config,
                        compute_target=aml_compute, 
                        source_directory=source_directory,
                        allow_reuse=GB_ALLOW_REUSE)
```

the code dataprep.py used in the STEP 1 is below:

```
##############################################
################# Libraries ##################
##############################################

##############################################
## Import libraries
import pandas as pd
import argparse
import logging
import sys
from pathlib import Path
from functions import *
from loguru import logger
##############################################

##############################################
############ General Definitions #############
##############################################

##############################################
# Container Name
GB_container_name = "videosraw"
GB_container_name_mp4 = "temp-mp4"
GB_container_name_mp4_original = "mp4-videos"
GB_container_name_json = "temp-container"
GB_container_name_ts_backup = "temp-container"
GB_container_name_video_texto = "temp-container"
GB_container_name_final_files = "temp-container"
##############################################

##############################################
# Datalake Credentials
GB_datalake_connstr_final = "xxxx"
GB_datalake_connstr = "yyyyy"
GB_datalake_connstr_mp4 = "zzzz"
##############################################

##############################################
################## Classes ###################
# ##############################################

##############################################
### Loguru InterceptHandler configuration
class InterceptHandler(logging.Handler):
    def emit(self, record):
        # Get corresponding Loguru level if it exists.
        try:
            level = logger.level(record.levelname).name
        except ValueError:
            level = record.levelno

        # Find caller from where originated the logged message.
        frame, depth = sys._getframe(6), 6
        while frame and frame.f_code.co_filename == logging.__file__:
            frame = frame.f_back
            depth += 1

        logger.opt(depth=depth, exception=record.exc_info).log(level, record.getMessage())

## Set Minimun level for logging for Storage Accounts logger
logging.getLogger("azure.core.pipeline.policies.http_logging_policy").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
## Set Minimun level for logging for MSREST
logging.getLogger('msrest').setLevel(logging.WARNING)
## Set Minimun level for logging for URLLib
logging.getLogger("urllib3").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
## Activate Intercept Handler
logging.basicConfig(handlers=[InterceptHandler()], level=0, force=True)

logger.add(sys.stdout, backtrace=True, diagnose=True, colorize=False, catch = True, level = "INFO")
##############################################

##############################################
################# Functions ##################
##############################################
print("Script execution completed")
logging.info("Script execution completed")
##############################################
### Parse arguments
def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--output-dir', dest='output_dir', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--node-count', dest='node_count', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--process-count', dest='process_count', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--batch-size', dest='batch_size', required=True)
    return parser.parse_args()

args = parse_args()
logger.info(f'Step arguments: {args.__dict__}')
##############################################

##############################################
################# Main Code ##################
##############################################

#Get WS context and def store
exp_run = Run.get_context()
ws = exp_run.experiment.workspace
def_store = ws.get_default_datastore() 

# Create output path from argument definition
p = Path(args.output_dir)
# First, make sure the directory exists
p.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
logger.info(f'Path inside OutputFileDatasetConfig created.')
logger.info(f'Starting check for non-processed files.')

# lista todos os blobs (arquivos) no contêiner especificado (devplaifurnasdlraw)
# do Azure Data Lake Storage, retornando os nomes, tamanhos e datas de modificação 
# desses blobs. 
## List all blobs for raw datastore - 
allblobs = DataLake_ListBlobs(GB_container_name, GB_datalake_connstr, 
                              '', ['name','size','last_modified'])

## Transform into a DataFrame
allblobsDF = pd.DataFrame(allblobs)

# allblobsDF['name'].str.contains('.ts'): Isso cria uma série (column) booleana 
# chamada allfiles, onde cada elemento é True se o nome de um blob (arquivo) na 
# coluna 'name' do DataFrame allblobsDF contiver a substring '.ts' (ou seja, se 
# o nome do arquivo contém '.ts'), e False caso contrário. Isso basicamente 
# filtra os blobs cujos nomes contêm '.ts'.
# .copy(): Isso cria uma cópia dos dados selecionados. A razão para criar uma 
# cópia é que, por padrão, ao fazer seleções em um DataFrame, você obtém uma 
# visualização dos dados originais, e não uma cópia. Criar uma cópia garante 
# que você tenha um novo DataFrame independente com os blobs que atendem ao critério.
allfiles = allblobsDF.loc[allblobsDF['name'].str.contains('.ts')].copy()

allfiles.reset_index(inplace = True)
allfiles.drop(labels = 'index', axis = 1, inplace = True)

# BUSCA O 'all_results_dataframe' DOS DATA ASSETS DO WORKSPACE
# Get dataset registered with results from all runs
processed_df = Dataset.get_by_name(ws, 'all_results_dataframe').to_pandas_dataframe()

# REMOVE OS DUPLICADOS OLHANDO PELA COLUNA 'Nome do Video'
processed_df = processed_df.drop_duplicates(subset='Nome do Video', ignore_index = True)

## Get diference
# FAZ DA COLUNA 'name' A COLUNA DOS INDICES EM allfiles
allfiles.set_index(keys = 'name')
# FAZ DA COLUNA 'Nome do Video' A COLUNA DOS INDICES processed_df
processed_df.set_index(keys = 'Nome do Video')

# Nessa linha, processDF é definido como um novo DataFrame que contém apenas as 
# entradas de allfiles que não têm índices presentes no índice de processed_df.
# ou seja processDF é o dataframe que já foi processado
processDF = allfiles[~allfiles.index.isin(processed_df.index)]

# notProcessDF é o dataframe que já foi processado
notProcessDF = allfiles[allfiles.index.isin(processed_df.index)]
processDF = processDF.reset_index().drop(columns = 'index')

logger.info(f"{len(notProcessDF)} files at origin Datalake were already processed! Skipping processing for these files.")
logger.info(f"{len(processDF)} files at origin Datalake queued to be processed!")

processDF = processDF.reset_index().drop(columns = 'index')

# Get Batch Size
batchSize = args.batch_size
# Logic for batch size "all" 
if batchSize != "all":
    batchSize = int(batchSize)
    # Batch definition
    if batchSize < len(processDF):
        processDF = processDF.iloc[:batchSize,:]
    else:
        pass
    logger.info(f'Batch size defined as {batchSize} files.')
else: 
    logger.info(f"Batch size defined to 'all' files.")
    
## Reset index to assure correct mini-batch distribution
processDF = processDF.reset_index().drop(columns = 'index')
fileQnty = len(processDF)
logger.success(f'Check for non-processed files endend. {fileQnty} files found and queued to be processed')

## Workers count
workers = (int(args.node_count) * int(args.process_count))
logger.info(f'Workers set to: {workers}')

## Create column for mini-batch distribution
for index, row in processDF.iterrows():
    processDF.loc[index, 'batch'] = index % workers

## Save dataframe with files to be processed
processDF.to_csv(p/'files_to_process.csv', index = False)

logger.success('Dataframe created and uploaded to OutputFileDatasetConfig object.')
logger.success('Data preparation ended.')
```

I do not create the pipe, I received it withou any documentation and I do not have the contact of the person who created it. The code use loguru to print the logs, but anything is printed when the cell of STEP 1 is executed. I tried with print() and whit logging.info() but in all cases nothing is returned to jupyter outpuc cell of STEP 1.

How can I solve it? How to print any information inside dataprep.py ?
I am new whit azure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your current setup, the print statements and logging from the `dataprep.py` script won't be displayed in the Jupyter Notebook output cell because the script is being executed as part of the PythonScriptStep in the Azure Machine Learning pipeline.

The output from the script will be captured in the logs of the pipeline run instead of the Jupyter Notebook output cell.

To view the logs from the pipeline run, you can use the `wait_for_completion` method with the `show_output=True` parameter.

Below is a sample code snippet:

```py
run = exp.submit(data_prep_step)
run.wait_for_completion(show_output=True)
```

This will display the logs from the pipeline run, including the print statements and logging from your `dataprep.py` script.

With the above method, once the pipeline is submitted.

[image]

You can get the output as shown below:
[image]

For more details regarding `script logs` you can check this [documentation.](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/machine-learning/v1/how-to-log-view-metrics.md#scriptrun-logs)